# Folder Level StorageItem location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

Iam look for the folder where my `StorageItem` is located.

[This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864182.aspx) says:

> A StorageItem object is stored at the folder level, allowing it to roam with the account and be available online or offline.

So my question is, what is the `folder level`? And what name does my `StorageItem` have? Is it hidden? What filetype does it have?

Comment: Can you also share with us the code you are using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sadly I cant..

Comment: Any small answer would still be highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MAPI folders have two contents tables - one is the regular contents table that the end user sees, and the hidden (associated) contents table where Outlook stores some per-folder config properties (such as view definitions, list of retrieved POP3 messages, categories, etc.).

Take a look at an Outlook folder with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click `IMAPIFolder` button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

Comment: These MAPI folders, where to they exist physically? Is there a path to this? Where are These associated items of my outlook addin?
Is it in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MYOUTLOOKADDIN

Or is it in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

I need to know this because I have to give the customer writing rights on the folder.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I mean even if theyre associated and I cant see them, they have to be somewhere on my storage shouldnt they? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: They are inside your PST or OST file. Outlook Items are not files.